# Apache Flink Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Traversable

Tags: apache-flink

I have just started learning Apache Flink and found the guide link to start the development in  EClipse IDE.

I followed the [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html) to start off but getting the below error

> 00:20:26,993 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - The job has 0 registered types and 0 default Kryo serializers
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Traversable
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Here I have place the Error log [log File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5obtqe6o4mrhen0/ApacheFlinkWordCount.log?dl=0)  ... Please let me know if your require more details. Thanks, Nyamath

Comment: I followed the [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html) to start off but getting the below error             00:20:26,993 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment                - The job has 0 registered types and 0 default Kryo serializers
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Traversable
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: Can you add a full stacktrace to your question? Without context it is hard to tell what the problem is. Thanks, Fabian

Comment: Here I have place the Error log [log File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5obtqe6o4mrhen0/ApacheFlinkWordCount.log?dl=0)  ... Please let me know if your require more details. Thanks, Nyamath

Comment: It looks as if one of the jars in your classpath has a bad signature, maybe even the scala library jar. Could you try to download them again or to delete your maven repository `~/.m2`?

Answer (score 0):

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Your Scala jar file provided by Maven seems to be corrupted. Please update your Maven dependencies by executing this from your project folder on the command line:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

In Eclipse, right click on your project and click on *Update - - > Maven dependencies*.

If that does not work you'll need to delete the corrupted Jar file in the `.m2/repositories/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you do not have all required Flink dependencies implicitly loaded into the classpath.

From Flink official document [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/try-flink/datastream/):

> Running the project in an IDE may result in a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception. This is probably because you do not have all required Flink dependencies implicitly loaded into the classpath.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA: Go to **Run > Edit Configurations > Modify options > Select include dependencies with "Provided" scope**. This run configuration will now include all required classes to run the application from within the IDE.

I guess configuration for Eclipse can be similar.